# Definition of Measure regular

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[image]

Book's, Real and complex analysis, Walter Rudin.

I am somewhat confused.

My question is:

"In other words, we are looking at $L^p$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,2\pi]$(or on $T$), divided by $2\pi$".

The (Lebesgue) measure in $[0,2 \pi]$ is the same as  $T$?

Thank you all.

Comment: The identification $T\mapsto [0,2\pi]$ (plus $2\pi$ periodicity) is an isometry, so the answer is something like "for all practical purposes, yes".

Comment: -----Thank  you----------